# how to make one route file and import it into bootstrap file Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I may have multiple route files which I do not wish to register into the app.js file. I made a router folder inside the router folder to create a route.js file wherein I will define the route file and export it into the app.js file but when I used app.use it says app.use() requires a middleware function. How can I make this correct?

```
App.js

import Router from './router/route';
app.use(Router);

route.js

import AbcController from '../controller/AbcController';
import XyzController from '../controller/XyzController';

export default {
  AbcController,
  XyzController,
};

AbcController.js

import {Router} from 'express';
const router = Router();

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

export default router;
```

if I export one file it does work e.g

routes.js

```
import AbcController from '../controller/AbcController';

export default AbcController;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the controllers as an array. You can use the following:

In route.js

```
import AbcController from '../controller/AbcController';
import XyzController from '../controller/XyzController';

export default [
  AbcController,
  XyzController,
]
```